# Grammar and meaning of 凝りに凝って出された

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

The author complains that when men cook they only put one dish (type of food) on the table:

> なぜならその一品は、素材を選び抜いて、奮発して、時間をかけて、腕によりをかけて、**凝りに凝って出された**逸品なのだから。
>   If (you ask) why that one dish, it's because it is a masterpiece in which he has singled out the ingredients, spent a lot of money, taken time, put all his skill into and ????

I can't understand the part in bold. 凝る has several meanings, none of which I can get to fit, nor do I understand the grammar of the pattern 凝りに凝って.

Also why do we switch to passive for だす when the rest of the sentence is in active voice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ａ（連用形）にＡ（活用） uses repetition of the same verb as a pattern for emphasis; the 活用 part is often seen as ～て or ～た.

Here 凝{こ}る means to pour an inordinate amount of focus / energy into something. To give something one's all, or to be absorbed in.

The passive is used here for 出す to change the focus from the subject (the person making the food), to the object (the dish being made).

> なぜならその一品は、素材を選び抜いて、奮発して、時間をかけて、腕によりをかけて、凝りに凝って出された逸品なのだから。

(Without context)
The reason why being that the dish served is something that he has agonized over choosing ingredients; something that he has taken time on and poured his all into doing his best work; a masterpiece he's been completely absorbed in.

Answer (score 6):

Repetition of verbs are very often used to emphasize the significance or insignificance of the speaker’s or hearer’s action. It depends on the context.
For instances:

選りも選ってこんな品を寄越したな！ – You sent me such a trash.

念には念を入れて調べてみろ – Check it with utmost caution.

言いも言ったり、あいつ俺のことを間抜けと言った - He said so indeed, he called me an idiot!

参った、参った! - I'm done, completely.

着くには着いたが、真夜中になった – We arrived there anyhow, but it was midnight when we got there.

聞くには聞いたが、覚えてない – I heard it certainly, but I don’t remember (what you said.)

読むには読んだが、何を書いているのか、理解できない – Certainly I read the book, but I was unable to understand what the author is trying to say.

描くには描いたが、一体何の絵やら – I drew a picture, but I’m not sure what it looks like.

Repetitions of adjectives are also frequently used with an attempt to emphasize the characteristics of the object it modifies, for instance:

白さも白し、富士の白雪　‐　White, really white snow of Mt.Fuji.

憎さも憎し、オレオレ詐欺男　－Really disgusting, base, and hateful "I'm Charly" swindle.